# go-pg different count fields in struct and table

Tags: go

I use go-pg library and specify row in table "unit"

```
type UnitModel struct {
    Id int
    Name string

    TableName struct{} `sql:"unit"`
}
```

but table unit contains more then 2 fields and when i call

```
var unit UnitModel
err := db.Model(&unit).Where("id = ?", id).Select()
```

get error "pg: can't find column alter_name in model".
How specify ignore other fields in table "unit"?

Answer (score 0):

Read [go-pg manual](https://github.com/go-pg/pg#select). There's an example, for your case is:

```
err := db.Model(&unit).Column("id", "name").Where("id = ?", id).Select()
```

Comment: Column("id", "name") call every time no good practic. I have dozens tables with special fields. Maybe i can specify mapping between struct fields and table fields?

Answer (score 0):

In version 4.8.10 go-pg this bug fixed. If db table contain fields which not exist in structure error will not occur.